# Extract just email headers in python

Tags: python, email, header

I'm having some issues trying to extract all the email headers in python. I know how to get the ones I'm looking for but I want to save all the headers and I'm not sure how to do that.

I have it loaded into a email object

```
import email
f = open(kwargs['opt_emailfile'])
msg = email.message_from_file(f)
f.close()
```

So I can get

```
msg['To']
msg['From']
```

But I want all the headers

Comment: Not sure if this will help anyone, but here's my two bits.  All I had to do (for one specific header) was `msg['Header_Name']`, and if the header exists, you get the contents, otherwise you get none.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using [HeaderParser](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html) perhaps:

```
from email.parser import HeaderParser
parser = HeaderParser()
h = parser.parsestr(email)

print h.keys()
```

I just noticed you edited your question. You can actually get the same information from what you had without using HeaderParser. e.g. `headers.items()` [will return](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.items) list of 2-tuples with headers and corresponding values.

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to have a variable named `email` since it the name of a module, even if you are not importing `email` directly.

Comment: This (and the OP's "solution" in the question itself) actually returns all the headers in order, even though the `keys()` sort of implies dictionary-like behavior.

Comment: Adapted this into an answer of my own to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42090598/874188

Comment: this also wors if the email is incomplete (headers only)