# extracting email Received: headers with Python email package

Tags: python, email

I'd like to extract the *Final* Received: email header from a message.  I have the Message as returned from `email.message_from_file()`.

Using the `Message.get()` or `Message.get_item()` methods don't guarantee which of the many Received: headers I will get.  `Message.get_all()` returns them all, but doesn't guarantee an order.  Is there a way to be guaranteed to get the last one?

Comment: Why would you need the final header? Surely the order of headers is not important?

Comment: @Will the order of the `Received:` headers does matter, as it indicates the order the message passed through the various servers that handled it.  The final one indicates the server where the message (supposedly) originated.  (They can be forged, of course.)  However as hd1 indicated in his reply, they are also timestamped, so I can just use that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3.6.7, the comments on the get_all() method explicity state that the values are returned in the same order as they are in the message, so `messageInstance.get_all('Received')` should work fine.

```
def get_all(self, name, failobj=None):
    """Return a list of all the values for the named field.

    These will be sorted in the order they appeared in the original
    message, and may contain duplicates.  Any fields deleted and
    re-inserted are always appended to the header list.

    If no such fields exist, failobj is returned (defaults to None).
    """
```

Answer (score 2):

`Received:` headers are timestamped:

```
Received: from lb-ex1.int.icgroup.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
by lb-ex1.localdomain (Postfix) with ESMTP id D6BDB1E26393
for <hd1@example.com>; Fri, 12 Dec 2014 12:09:24 -0500 (EST)
```

So, do `messageInstance.get_all()` and [sort](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) the resulting list however you see fit, an example of how to do this:

```
import email.utils
import operator
def sort_key(received_header):
    received_date = email.utils.parsedate_tz(received_header)
    return received_date

received_header_list.sort(key=sort_key)
```

If it doesn't work, do leave a comment and I'll be happy to look into it further.

Comment: Thanks, silly of me to forget I could use the time stamps. :)

Comment: But keep in mind that in the real world, not all server clocks are exact. I'm pretty sure the order of the headers is much more reliable than the timestamps.

Comment: Also, in the real world, many servers use odd formats for `Received` headers which are not guaranteed to be machine-readable or useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `email.parser` class `HeaderParser` implements a dictionary-like interface, but actually seems to return the headers in the order you expect.

```
from email.parser import HeaderParser

headers = HeaderParser().parse(open_filehandle, headersonly=True)
for key, value in headers.items():
    if key == 'Received':
        ... do things with the value
```

The [`parse` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.Parser.parse) has a sister [`parsestr` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.Parser.parsestr) which accepts a byte string instead of a file-like object.

If by "final" you mean the "newest", that will be the first one which matches the `if` so you can simply `break` after reading it.  If by "final" you mean something else, you can implement that inside the `if` in whatever way you see fit.

This is adapted from [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424317/extract-just-email-headers-in-python).