# python poplib get headers from emails

Tags: python, email, pop3, poplib

this is my actula code :

```
import poplib, sys, re, threading, time, Queue
from email import parser

    Mailbox = poplib.POP3(pop3, '110')
    Mailbox.user(username)
    Mailbox.pass_(password)
    numMessages = len(Mailbox.list()[1])
    for i in range(numMessages):
            fullemail = ''
            fullemail = '\n'.join([msg for msg in Mailbox.retr(i+1)[1]])
            msg = parser.Parser().parsestr(fullemail)
            for part in msg.walk():
                    print part.get_payload(decode=True)
```

print part.get_payload(decode=True) print body of email, how i can print header of email ?

Comment: You are not showing your imports but if you are using the Python `email` library, the currently second example on https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html shows you how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract just email headers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424317/extract-just-email-headers-in-python)

Comment: If you think "the body" is well-defined, perhaps your understanding of email isn't yet very deep.

Answer (score 0):

the method `items()` of `email.message.Message`/`email.message.EmailMessage` object may be useful:

```
for t in msg.items():
    print(t)
```

t is a tuple like this `(key,value).`