# how to find the smtp server of an email address python

Tags: python, email, dns, smtp

so i have an email address like: `example@unknowndomain.com`

i want to check what is the smtp host that this email is connected to

is there any way i can do this in python?

at the end i want to check if smtp host of the email matches a certain host i have like:

```
email = example@unknowndomain.com
smtp_host = smtp.smtphost.com
email_smtp_host =smtp.emailsmtphost.com

if email_smtp_host == smtp_host:
   True
else:
    False
```

i tried looking through the smtplib but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: Usually it is the part after the `@` (i think). So just do `email.split('@')[1]`.

Comment: @Haveaniceday its not actually, i checked it on thunderbird and its different than the domain of the email

Comment: Ok, just thought I'd mention as it has worked for me before :).

Comment: "i want to check what is the smtp host that this email is connected to" Why?Do you need to test for email reachability? If so, there is no other solution than actually sending an email with a temporary URL in it and asking the receiver to click on it.That will fully verify the email address works at the time this is done. Even if you achieve to get the SMTP host per Edo Akse reply,it does not really conclude anything about the email address. The host can be down, or misconfigured and refuse the emails, etc. Also your test on name in the code is concerning, a given host can have multiple names.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can simply get by code. The SMTP server is the outgoing mail server and this depends on the email provider. There is no standard in this, and these are not exposed like the MX records for incoming email.

You *might* be able to find a list of SMTP servers such as [this one](https://domar.com/smtp_pop3_server) but you would still need to know who the email provider is. You *might* be able to figure this out by looking at the [MX records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) for the domain, and then choose the SMTP server based on that.

**Example:**
Needs installation of the non-default `dnspython` module using `pip install dnspython`

```py
import dns.resolver
domain = 'gmail.com'
for x in dns.resolver.resolve(domain, 'MX'):
    print(x.to_text())
```

This should print out the MX records for the domain `gmail.com`, which you would then have to check against some database containing the SMTP servers for all the email providers (linked to their MX records)

As I stated, this is not something that can be done easily and would require quite a bit of groundwork/legwork...

Comment: what if i tried to catch the incoming IMAP host, would that be possible through code?

Comment: that depends on whether you have access to the email headers (I'm not exactly clear on the information you have). Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8424563/9267296) and then the header you are interested in is the `Received` one. Send yourself an email to your Gmail address and follow [this article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/29436/trace-an-email-with-its-full-headers) from Google to see the headers, and look at how the `Received` one looks like. If you have access to the email headers then some logic should be able to figure out the SMTP server...

Comment: also, the IMAP host itself is for outgoing email. You would still need a way to tie that to the incoming SMTP server. Note that the whole exercise becomes moot if the email address for which you are trying to find the SMTP server is running his own email server, which is actually more common then you might think. Getting the SMTP server for these without having access to the mentioned email headers is an exercise in futility

Comment: (and if the `MX` query fails, you have to retry for `A` and `AAAA` records as direct ones are valid instead of missing `MX` records)